# Markup for editing SObject fields in Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds

Not having looked for a while, I was hoping that the set of field-level components for Lightning would be more complete now. But for example...

There is [force:inputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_inputField.htm) that renders picklist options (albeit without using a select list) and is hooked up to other metadata but:

> This component doesn't inherit the Lightning Design System styling. Use lightning:input if you want an input field that inherits the Lightning Design System styling.

Then there is [lightning:input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm) that has the correct styling you find there is no meta-data information such as picklist values hooked up for you so a picklist field just renders as a text edit field.

Am I missing something that is in the platform today? Any 3rd party libraries that help?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct here .There are gaps .Force namespace does not obey styling while lightning:input is still in BETA and it only provides JS functions and lightning design system CSS .

While safe harbor applies ,there seems to be plan to expand and provide lightning version of inputfield.

There is one from Doug on git which handles picklists well.

[Lightning Picklist Component](https://github.com/DouglasCAyers/sfdc-lightning-picklist-field-component)